# 500 server error when using jenkins python module build_job(job_name, parameters=) method

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration

`server.build_job(self.job_full_name, parameters=params)` when parameters is not `None`, `jenkins.JenkinsException: Error in request. Possibly authentication failed [500]: Server Error` occurs. It works when `parameters=None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may appear when the job you are trying to build with python-jenkins doesn't require any parameters, so if you try to pass some, it just fails.
Please, doublecheck this.
Hope, it will help

Comment: I forgot adding parameters in job configuration. It works now.